# How to know the classpath in an EAR with ClassLoader in WebLogic?

Tags: java, weblogic, classpath

I'm trying to get the classpath (**all the libraries that the project has loaded**), at the moment I'm trying using this statement :

```
ClassLoader jre = JREvaluator.class.getClassLoader();
```

What I get is :

```
weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader @ 109774a
```

From here, how can I get the classpath if I'm working with **WebLogic**. I've aready used many options found over internet but this class doesn't allow some methods as : **URLClassLoader.getURLs(**) because it belongs to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap classloader is the root of the Java classloader hierarchy. The Java virtual machine (JVM) creates the bootstrap classloader, which loads the Java development kit (JDK) internal classes and java.* packages included in the JVM. (For example, the bootstrap classloader loads java.lang.String.)

The extensions classloader is a child of the bootstrap classloader. The extensions classloader loads any JAR files placed in the extensions directory of the JDK. This is a convenient means to extending the JDK without adding entries to the classpath. However, anything in the extensions directory must be self-contained and can only refer to classes in the extensions directory or JDK classes.

The system classpath classloader extends the JDK extensions classloader. The system classpath classloader loads the classes from the classpath of the JVM. Application-specific classloaders (including WebLogic Server classloaders) are children of the system classpath classloader.
For more information on weblogic classloader refer below
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13706/classloading.htm#WLPRG285

-verbose:dynload and -verbose:class gives more information on the class that are loaded.
https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSTCZ_2.0.0/com.ibm.softrt.aix32.doc/realtime/rt_standard_options.html

For more class related JVM arguments.

Comment: Your explication is good, thanks. However, I don't looking about java parameter when loading WebLogic cause I don't have that access. I've already found the response. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was necessary to look up original code from **weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader** and I found this method :

```
 public String getClassPath() { ... }
```

With that methods it's really easy to get all the internal jars of your applications.